# Can "each of which" be reduced to "each"

Tags: relative-clauses

I wrote:

> Regular expressions can be used to match several patterns, **each of which** is enclosed in parentheses.

Could it be:

> Regular expressions can be used to match several patterns, **each** enclosed in parentheses.

How about:

> Regular expressions can be used to match several patterns, **where each pattern** is enclosed in parenthesis.

---

**Update**:
Example:

`([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)` to match `12-04-1975`

The above expression contains three patterns, each enclosed in parentheses.

Comment: Yes is the simple answer, though the grammar is different. In your first example "each of which" is a relative phrase introducing a relative clause where "patterns" is the antecedent. In your second example "each" is a fused determiner-head whose salient meaning is "each pattern" which heads the gerund-participial clause "each (pattern) enclosed in parenthesis".

Comment: But you'd want to say "enclosed in parenthes**e**s".

Comment: If you choose **each of which** or **where each pattern** you need a finite verb as predicate, "*is* enclosed".

Comment: @BillJ you mean in my second sentence I should use a dot (end of sentence) before *each*?

Comment: @Ahmad No, it's fine as it is.

Comment: @BillJ thanks, still no one said me, which of them is more fluent and preferred! I myself prefer the second sentence with just a single *each*.

Comment: @Ahmad Well, it's a matter of style, of personal choice. I prefer the succinct 2nd example, but there's little to choose between them.

Answer (score 1):

As **@BillJ** commented:

**"each of"which"** and **"each"** can be both used interchangeably, however:

1. Regular expressions can be used to match several patterns, **each of which** is enclosed in parentheses.

**"Each of which"** means **"each of the several patterns"**. **"Each of which"** here requires a verb after it.

2. Regular expressions can be used to match several patterns, **each** enclosed in parentheses.

**"Each"** means **"pattern"**. Here **"each"** doesn't require a verb after it.

3. Regular expressions can be used to match several patterns, **where each pattern** is enclosed in parenthesis.

It is also grammatically correct and carries the same meaning.